# Marshal unmanaged array of structs to managed array

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I would like to cleanly and efficiently transmit a custom struct of colored points from my C++ application into my C# application.

Under the hood, the custom structs are composed of floats.  So, before, I would break things down into an array of floats and then rebuild the structures after doing a `Marshal.Copy`, but this is not clean or very maintainable.  I would like to be able to perform a mass copy similar to that, but fill in the elements of my C# array at the same time.  I've started down that path by serializing my c++ array into a buffer of bytes with a known count of points and pass that over, but the mass copy part of it eludes me.  The code below works, but takes a call to `Marshal.PtrToStructure` at each memory address, which is too slow.

C# code

```
    protected override void TransferPoints( IntPtr points, int count )
    {
        PointXYZRGB[] colorPoints = new PointXYZRGB[ count ];

        for( int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // Works but is too slow
            colorPoints[i] = (PointXYZRGB) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(points + (32 * i), typeof(PointXYZRGB));
        }
    }
```

A Colored Point

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=16)]
    public struct PointXYZRGB 
    {
        public Vector3Data Position;

        public Color3Data Color;
    }
```

Vector3Data and Color3Data are both structs that are just composed of three floats

```
    [Serializable]
    public struct Vector3Data
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
    }
```

```
    [Serializable]
    public struct Color3Data
    {
        public float r;
        public float g;
        public float b;
    }
```

C++ function template looks like this

```
void TransferPoints( uint8_t* buffer, int32_t counts );
```

When I try to do something like this to copy everything at once I don't get any values back.

```
        protected override void TransferPoints( IntPtr points, int count )
        {
            PointXYZRGB[] colorPoints = new PointXYZRGB[ count ];

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(points, colorPoints);
        }
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions!

**Edit**
More context: My C# code subscribes to the point list, and it does that through the `TransferPoints` delegate

```
public class ManagedPointWrapper
{
    [DllImport("example.so")]
    public static extern IntPtr newPointXYZRGBSubscriber( IntPtr transferPoints );
}
```

Creating the subscriber

```
ManagedPointWrapper.newPointXYZRGBSubscriber(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate( transferXYZRGBPointsCallback ) );
```

The delegate looks like this:

```
    /// Delegate declaration for the callback to be passed into the c++ interop layer
    /// </summary>
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void TransferXYZRGBPointsDelegate(IntPtr xyzrgb, Int32 count);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  When you say I need to call [Out] on the _buffer_ parameter, you're referring to the C++ function call?  AFAIK C++ would not have an [Out] I could set on it, and if I should be setting that on the IntPtr at the top, if anything, it would be [In], not [Out], this function call gets triggered from C++.  I think I follow the rest of your comment.

Comment: Hopefully the added context is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your target runtime/platform allows, consider using the generic overload for improved performance:

```
  ///<summary>[Supported in the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and later versions]
  ///Marshals data from an unmanaged block of memory to a managed object of the specified type.</summary>
  ///<param name="ptr">A pointer to an unmanaged block of memory.</param>
  ///<param name="structure">The object to which the data is to be copied.</param>
  ///<typeparam name="T">The type of <paramref name="structure" />. This must be a formatted class.</typeparam>
  ///<exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">Structure layout is not sequential or explicit.</exception>
  static member PtrToStructure<'T> : ptr: nativeint * structure: 'T -> unit
```